# In Java, what command line makes the computer click on the screen?

Tags: java, automation

I'm making an auto-clicker and I can't find what command line will make the computer click on the screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simulate mouse movements and clicks with Java's [Robot](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.